# parent view clipChildren strange behaviour (not working at a point)

Tags: android, android-layout

Greetings Stack community.

I am creating this post because I am running in a problem that I can't seem to solve or even correctly figure out why this happens. I have been an Android dev for kind of nearly 3 years so I think I know my way around, but in this case I have a blocking issue.

The problem I have is related to viewGroups and child views where the child has a width bigger than the one of the parent. I have tried setting `clipChildren = false` and `clipToPadding = false` to all the parent views in the hierarchy, but they work until a specific point and that is up to the first generation of the root parent viewGroup. I have made a simplified version of my problem so that you can also see for yourself what my problem and question concretely is. Below is the test layout ready for copy paste so you can simulate my problem:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="400dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#55ff0000"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#ffacde"
    android:clipChildren="false">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@color/accent_material_light"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <!--
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:background="@color/accent_material_dark">
        </FrameLayout>
        //-->


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/sdfIasdftem"
            android:layout_width="140dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="#4f0f5f00"
            android:clipChildren="false">


            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/sdfItem"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:background="#ffffff00"
                android:clipChildren="false">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/middleItem"
                    android:layout_width="60dp"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:background="#ff0000ff"
                    android:clipChildren="false">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="300dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        android:background="#00ff00"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Hello" />

                </FrameLayout>

            </FrameLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <!--
          <FrameLayout android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="60dp" android:background="#99550066">

          </FrameLayout>
        -->

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Now the child that i want to show stays unclipped until

`<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="230dp"`

Can anybody explain why this happens and maybe how to overcome this? To me it looks really strange. If you add `clipChildren = false` to the root `FrameLayout` than it works, but it should not depend on this so the question is still present.

Thank you for taking your time in reading this and helping me with this sophisticated puzzle.

Best regards.

Rubin

Comment: Why not use a Image that has boxes of different color that you want to achieve and set it to single layout

Comment: In my case it is not my intention to show an image with those boxes. In this xml that I have shown there I have just created a layout to help you and other people better understand the problem with which I am dealing.